# Hide Laravel 5.5 Programming Language

Tags: laravel, cookies, session-cookies

I have a problem with hiding the programming Language (Laravel 5.5) of my website
I tried a lot of different ways but did not get any result.
I changed my session `config/session.php`:

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
```

but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Is `SESSION_COOKIE` set in your `.env` file?

Comment: `env( 'SESSION_COOKIE', str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session' )` means, read on the `.env` file for `SESSION_COOKIE` if it does not exist, the second parameter will be the return value. hence, as trembly asked, "have you set `SESSION_COOKIE` on your `.env` file?"

Comment: No i didn't set it in .env file ; its' : SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120 by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to show the programming language of your Website in Chrome extensions then you have to change the setting in `php.ini`

change `expose_php = On`

to

`expose_php = off`

You can also tweak it in your .htaccess.
Hope it helps.

Comment: it isn't work too ; it only don't show the version; in my .htaccess is like : 
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]  # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Comment: @mopaco you can also remove the php header from apache configs

Answer (score 0):

You may need this basically for security reasons. When somebody installed this plugin (https://wappalyzer.com/download) on the browser, s/he can see all the frameworks and javascript libraries among other things.

So hide framwork name from plugin , just go in `config/session.php` file and edit bellow code

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'yourname_that_you_want_to_add'), '_').'_session'
    ),
```